# How to apply mouse Click event for 3D model

Tags: html, canvas, three.js, webgl

Added 3D collada (.dae) file in to a scene. The 'DAE' file contains geometry with the name "monster" and the id is "monster-mesh-skin". I tried to apply mouse click event to the geometry "monster". like,

```
var monster = dae.getChildByName("monster"); // get geometry
monster.addEventListener("click", meshClickHandler);
```

The click event is not working. And I tried `THREE.Vector3()` and `THREE.Ray` like,

```
var mouse3D = new THREE.Vector3();
mouse3D.x = event.clientX;
mouse3D.y = event.clientY;
mouse3D.z = 0.5;

var ray = new THREE.Ray(mouse3D);

var intersects = ray.intersectObjects(monster);
console.dir(intersects);
```

on document click handler. In intersects variable not contain any value.

Is there any solution to apply mouse event for 3D model and control it?

Comment: This questions does not show any research effort ....

Answer (score 1):

It appears you need to rethink the approach a bit. Any 3D object in your scene exists exclusively as a 2D "drawing" of an object and itself can not have standard DOM event handlers attached to it.

What you want is a general event listener on the document itself to capture mouse clicks, like so:

```
document.addEventListener( 'click', detectIntersect, false );
```

Now, there are a ton of example right in Three.js example directory that can show you exactly how to "click your object", but in 3D terms it's refered to as **object picking** or **raycasting an object**. These terms might help when searching for examples/help. Have a look at these examples:

http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_interactive_cubes.html
http://threejs.org/examples/canvas_interactive_cubes_tween.html

One last note, it appears your using r57 or earlier of the Three.js library. I would suggest upgrading to the latest build as getting support from the community is easier when were all on the same page :)

Hope that helps, take care.